# Q: Find the relation betwen $P(X=1)P(Y=1)$ and $P(X=1,Y=1)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Q: An experiment has two optional result, $1$ and $0$. The result is $1$ with the probabily of $Z$, where $Z$ is a continuous r.v. with the following density:

$f_Z(z) = 
\begin{cases}
  cz^a(1-z^b)& ,0 \le \ z \le 1 \\
  1 & ,o.w.
\end{cases}$
, when $a,b,c \ge0$

The experiment is done twice, let $X,Y$ be the the results of the first and the second time respectively.
Find out for which values of $a,b,c$ the relations $\ge,=,<$ are holding between $P(X=1)P(Y=1)$  and $P(x=1,y=1)$.

My attempts:
$P(X=1)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}P(X=1\mid Z=z)f_Z(z)dz=\int\limits_{0}^{1}cz^{a+1}(1-z^b)=\frac{bc}{(a+2)(a+b+2)}$ .
For symmetry reasons $P(X=1)=P(Y=1)$, so $P(X=1,Y=1)=\Bigl(\frac{bc}{(a+2)(a+b+2)}\Bigr)^2$.

What I don't understand is how to find $P(X=1,Y=1)$, since $f_{X,Y}$ is not given.
Please try to keep your answers simple enough for an undergraduate taking his first course in probability.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect you must go for $P(X=1,Y=1\mid Z)=Z^2$ so that $P(X=1,Y=1)=\mathbb EZ^2$.

Comment: @drhab we didn't learn the theorem you seem to use, is there any way similar to what I did on my previous attempts? also, wouldn't $P(X=1,Y=1∣Z)=Z^2$ mean that $X,Y$ are independent?

Comment: If that helps, the answer should be $\forall a,b,c \ge 0 :  P(X=1)P(Y=1)<P(X=1,Y=1)$

Comment: Well, if $X,Y$ are indeed dependent then why would you be asked about the relation between $P(X=1)P(Y=1)=P(X=1=Y)$?.... That would simply be equality, right? Note that (if I am correct) $P(X=1,Y=1)-P(X=1=Y)=\mathbb EZ^2-(\mathbb EZ)^2=\mathsf{Var}(Z)>0$. So that agrees with the answer. I think that the same $Z$ is used for determining both probabilities $P(X=1)$ and $P(Y=1)$.

Comment: @drhab I guess you mean if $X,Y$ are indeed independent the relation is the equality. Unfortunately we didn't got to learn something that can make me conclude that $P(X=1,Y=1∣Z)=Z^2$ implies $P(X=1,Y=1)=E(Z)$, so I can't use it in the exam.  The only problem I have is for the multiplication of the two Z terms, isn't it says at least that $X=1\mid Z$ and $ Y=1\mid Z$ are independent?

Comment: You start with $P(X=1)=\int_0^1P(X=z\mid Z=z)f_Z(z)dz$ but probably meant $P(X=1)=\int_0^1P(X=1\mid Z=z)f_Z(z)dz=\int_0^1zf_Z(z)dz=\mathbb EZ$. In the same way you can find: $P(X=1,Y=1)=\int P(X=1,Y=1\mid Z=z)f_Z(z)dz=\int z^2f_Z(z)dz=\mathbb EZ^2$.

Comment: Anyway, in your attempt the expression $P(X=z\mid Z=z)$ is probably a typo and must be changed into $P(X=1\mid Z=z)$ (for $X$ only $0$ and $1$ are options). The further working out of it looks okay to me and results in $\mathbb EZ$. Being equipped with that you can do the same for finding $P(X=1,Y=1)$ (so not an unkown theorem is used).

Comment: @drhab it is a typo, thanks for pointing it out. Also, thanks for your help. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly reduced (in spite of the repaired typo):

- $P(Y=1)=P(X=1)=\int P(X=1\mid Z=z)f_Z(z)dz=\int zf_Z(z)dz=\mathbb EZ$.

Similarly we find:

- $P(X=1,Y=1)=\int P(X=1,Y=1\mid Z=z)f_Z(z)dz=\int z^2f_Z(z)dz=\mathbb EZ^2$.

Then:$$P(X=1,Y=1)-P(X=1)P(Y=1)=\mathbb EZ^2-(\mathbb EZ)^2=\mathsf{Var}Z>0$$