# ratio of exponential independent random variables (with limitations on the soltion)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X,Y$ be indpendent exponential randonm variables with the same parameter $\lambda$.
Define $Z=\frac{Y}{X}$, find $f_z(z)$ , the PDF of $Z$.

Now here's the deal: this question was asked previously over here, however - in my solution i'm limited to a solution not including the use of an expected value or any theorems involving change of variables (I really don't know the right term because we didn't learned such theorem at my class on university).
Check how I solved a previous question to get an idea of the desired solution type [over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4059033/q-find-the-relation-betwen-px-1py-1-and-px-1-y-1).

My efforts:

- $F_{_Z}(z) = P(\frac{Y}{X}\le z) = P(Y\le Xz) = \int\limits_0^\infty P(Y\le xz, X\color{red}=x)dx$
  but that fails since $P(Y\le xz, X=x) = P(Y\le xz)P(X=x)=0$
- $F_{_Z}(z) = \int\limits_0^\infty P(Y\le xz, X \color{red}\le x)dx = \int\limits_0^\infty F_{_Y}(xz)F_{_X}(x)dx = \int\limits_0^\infty(1-e^{-\lambda xz})(1-e^{-\lambda x})dx$
  but that will go to infinity.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: You made a mistake in the first bullet: $$P[Y \leq X z] = \int_0^{\infty} P[Y \leq Xz|X=x]f_X(x)dx$$

Comment: @Michael but isn't it the same? since $P(Y\le Xz \mid X =x)f_X(x) = \frac{P(Y \le Xz , X=x)}{f_X(x)}\cdot f_X(x)$

Comment: No.  Those are not the same.  As you know, the numerator on the right-hand-side is zero.

Comment: @Michael so what is the equivilent if I move from conditioned probability to the intersection? also, I will edit and try again as you sugested

Comment: If you want to derive it in a limiting form, and if $A$ is an event and $f_X(x)$ is continuous at the point $x$ and $f_X(x)>0$, then  for $\delta\approx 0$:  $$P[A | X\in [x, x+\delta]] = \frac{P[A \cap X \in [x, x+\delta]]}{P[X \in [x, x+\delta]]} \approx \frac{P[A \cap X \in [x, x+\delta]]}{f_X(x)\delta} $$ and so $$ P[A | X \in [x, x+\delta]] f_X(x) \approx \frac{P[A \cap X \in [x, x+\delta]]}{\delta}$$

Comment: @Michael thanks, I'm actually learning to an exam, so as much exciting it seems - it probably involves more theory behind it and im certainly wouldn't be able to use that. Is the second bullet alright, though? and trying to move to the conditioned probability led me nowhere, it seems I need more tools to solve this problem

Comment: You seem to be making up equations in both your first and second bullets.  On an exam, it is not a good idea to just make up your own equations and pretend they are true. Do you know the "law of total probability in integral form"? It is the very first comment I gave, and if you know it then you do not need to derive it.  It was the closest-match true equation to what I thought you were trying to do. Or else you can just integrate the joint PDF over the region of all $(x,y)$ that satisfy $y \leq xz$.

Comment: well, thats because I am just doing things that were somewhat intuitive to me, but weren't actually taught. Also it's not so clear to me when to integrate the joint PDF, we learnt simple things, but that seems really loose connected to the way we learnt. I guess the idea of the question is to use the joint PDF, I will look more into it. Thank you very much

Comment: You can either use the law of total probability in integral form and derive the answer in just a few more lines starting with my first comment (the next line being to substitute the given info $X=x$), or you can integrate the joint PDF over $\int\int _{(x,y): y\leq xz}$.

Comment: the law of total probability in integral form is something we didn't learnt this semester. I looked back at my lecture notes and it says there that $P((X,Y)\in D) = \iint_D f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$, just as you suggested. I guess the examples I saw were too trivial (rectangular zones only). Please collect your comments into an answer, I'd be glad to accept it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer summarizes my comments. There are two basic ways:

**1. Integrate the joint PDF:**

$$ P[(X,Y) \in D] = \int \int_D f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$$
In this case, by independence, we know $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$. Thus
\begin{align*}
P[Y \leq Xz] &= \int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{y=-\infty}^{xz} f_X(x)f_Y(y)dydx \\
&= \int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} \left[\int_{y=-\infty}^{xz} f_Y(y)dy  \right]f_X(x)dx
\end{align*}

**2. Law of total probability in integral form:**

\begin{align*}
P[Y\leq Xz] &= \int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} P[Y \leq Xz|X=x] f_X(x)dx \\
&= \int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} P[Y \leq xz|X=x] f_X(x)dx \\
&= \int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} P[Y\leq xz]f_X(x)dx
\end{align*}
where the final equality holds by independence.  Since
$$ P[Y \leq xz] = \int_{y=-\infty}^{xz} f_Y(y)dy$$
we can see the two methods give the same answer.